# Redux: state won't display array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I have two examples in a database which is structured in the state as follows:

```
state:
  interaction: [
    {creatorId: 123,
     title: exampleTitle1
    },
    {creatorId: 1234,
     title: exampleTitle2}
  ]
```

the store is this:

```
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...(other reducers)
    interaction: interactionReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

I fetch bases from the API upon `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchBases());
}
```

With this action creator:

```
export const BASE_SUCCESS = "BASE_SUCCESS";
export const baseSuccess = bases => ({
    type: BASE_SUCCESS,
    bases,
});
```

and the action (when i console log `action` the array returns just fine):

```
export const fetchBases = () => dispatch => {
  fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/base/list`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(res.statusText);
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(bases => dispatch(baseSuccess(bases)))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("GET request failed", error);
  });
};
```

The reducer:

```
export default function interactionReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === BASE_SUCCESS) {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        bases: action.bases,
      });
    }
    return state;
}
```

In the component, i have the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    bases: state.bases,
});

export default requiresLogin()(connect(mapStateToProps)(DashContent));
```

When I console log `this.state` in the component i get a log of `null`. I cannot figure out to save my life why it is not populating the data correctly. Earlier it showed just one item in the array, but now it is null

Comment: `this.state`? Is there any local state in your component. Have you checked with: `this.props.bases`?

Comment: Also, it should be `bases: state.interaction.bases` since you have an `interaction` state in your global state.

Answer (score 0):

You should open your state like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    bases: state.interaction.bases,
});
```

since you have an `interaction` state in the global one. Also, you can't see any state with `this.state` since it points to the local state of your app. You can reach your state with `props` as `this.props.bases`.